# Analogue of $\ell^2(X)$ over an arbitrary Banach ring

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, condensed-mathematics

Let $X$ be a set. Over the Banach fields $F=\mathbb{R}$ or $F=\mathbb{C}$ we can define the Banach space$$\ell^2(X)=\{\xi\colon X\to F\mid \sum_{x\in X}|\xi(x)|^2<\infty\}$$which satisfies a list of very interesting properties, namely:

1. $\ell^2(X)$ is a Banach $F$-vector space.
2. There is function $\delta\colon X\to\ell^2(X)$ that sends a point $x\in X$ to the function $\delta_x$ that is $1$ on $x$ and $0$ otherwise satisfying the following universal property: For any $\xi\colon X\to F$ in $\ell^2(X)$, there exists a unique continuous $F$-linear function $\tilde{\xi}\colon\ell^2(X)\to F$ commuting the triangle $\xi=\tilde{\xi}\circ\delta$.

Over $F$ we can describe $\tilde{\xi}$ as the function $\langle\xi, -\rangle$ using the Riesz representation theorem. We can represent inumerous interesting objects on $\ell^2(X)$ such group(oid) $F$-algebras over this Hilbert space $\ell^2(X)$.

Is there an analogue for $\ell^2(X)$ over a general Banach ring $R$? Some "topological/bornological/condensed" $R$-module $M$ that is complete in some sense satisfying some version of property (2.) above?

Comment: I think 2. is not true as stated, actually. Taking $X=\mathbb N$, this would be saying that for any null-sequence $(\xi_n)_n$ and any $\ell^2$-sequence $(\xi'_n)_n$, the sum $\sum_n \xi_n \xi'_n$ exists, which is not true. To make it true, you should assume that $\xi: X\to F$ is itself $\ell^2$.

Comment: @PeterScholze Yes, you are completely right. Edited.